# Is it possible to install a device driver for windows on mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, drivers

My university acquired a very specialised device, and in order to control it I need my computer to have the appropriate driver. However, the company manufacturing the device only provides a driver for windows, and I am using a macbook running the latest macOS version. Is it possible to somehow install the driver without having to ialso install windows on my computer?

Comment: The current version of macOS only works on Apple silicon, which at it's core is ARM hardware, while the Windows drivers you want to use only support x86-64.  I would normally suggest running a VM, but there is no legal way, to run Windows 10 on ARM on Apple hardware since there is no legal way to purchase Windows 10 on ARM without purchasing a qualifying device.

Comment: @Ramhound - The current version of macOS works just fine on [Intel or Apple Silicon](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213264). Windows on ARM is perfectly possible to run legitimately on Apple Silicon too. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/options-for-using-windows-11-with-mac-computers-with-apple-m1-and-m2-chips-cd15fd62-9b34-4b78-b0bc-121baa3c568c Windows on ARM usually does a decent job of emulating X86-64.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Clearly, "Windows 11 Pro product keys are platform agnostic (x64 vs Arm).", is news to me.  Windows 11 on ARM used to be only available on eligible ARM devices. Looking further into it, Windows on ARM, would still require compatible drivers for the platform. It's unclear if drivers targeted specifically for Arm64 would support Apple silicon.

Comment: @Ramhound - the OP didn't mention ARM at all. Presumably someone making esoteric devices & windows-only drivers isn't going to be targeting the average ARM user either, but run-of-the-mill Wintel users. Once you can squeeze Win/ARM onto a Mac, Windows itself handles the ARM/Intel translation; the Mac can't & doesn't.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I just assume it's Apple silicone since modern Macs are being transitioned to it.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, as far as the OP is concerned. Either way, they're going to have to run Windows to use the driver, whether on Boot Camp or in VM.

Comment: Do you connect the device to the computer using USB? If yes, it should be possible to run a virtual machine on macOS host, and within that run a Windows guest, and configure the virtual machine to pass some USB devices through to the guest. If it's not USB, then such a device passthrough may still be possible, you should check the documentation of your virtual machine software.

Comment: Depending on the device and the driver, it can be simple, or it can be the beginning of some sleepless nightmare. However, I am mostly speaking from experiences on some Linux based operating system, and your mileage may vary on Mac OS.

Comment: Get your university to buy a Windows PC. They don't have to be terribly expensive nowadays. They are certainly cheaper than Macbooks.

Comment: @user253751 Depending on how demanding the driver and any associated software is, a Windows PC can be cheaper than a Macbook. Or it can be significantly more expensive to buy. A current gen M1 Macbook Air costs 1000 USD. A Windows laptop with comparable performance will cost at least 1300 USD, and maybe more.

Comment: Can you tell us any more specifics about the device itself and what it does ?

Comment: @nzall: Maybe "a Windows laptop with comparable performance, fit, and finish" might potentially cost that much, but you can beat the performance for half that.  Even less, because the situation doesn't appear to call for a laptop, it calls for a Windows PC permanently connected to the piece of specialized equipment.

Comment: @Tetsujin:  Wouldn't the driver need to be compiled for ARM, or can Windows emulate x86 even for drivers?

Comment: @OskarSkog - I have no idea, sorry. The question is vague, the answer is vague. UTM says it can emulate hardware… I'd say try it & see.

Comment: @OskarSkog Apple Silicon Macs can execute x86-64 binaries using Apple's software translation mechanism to Arm instructions called [Rosetta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_\(software\)). But this is not applicable in this case, since the binary is presumably using Windows system calls and there's probably some difference in how Windows configures hardware and how it expects you to talk to it.

Comment: For fun (assuming the binary isn't large) you could run `objdump` on the driver binary file and paste parts of the output into ChatGPT and ask it to convert it into a macOS (Arm or x86-64) driver but it's not going to work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No.

At the most basic level, the Mac will have no idea what it is or what to do with it. It won't even install, there's nowhere to put it. The Mac won't even understand what the installer is.
The two operating systems speak completely different languages & there is no simple translator.

To answer the last part of the question directly - you need Windows, either in Boot Camp or a VM [depending on your platform, Intel or 'ARM' Apple Silicon.]

Comment: NOTE: If driver means Intel kernel driver you can't run it on ARM Windows, ruling out virtualization on Apple Silicon. Windows for ARM cannot emulate kernel drivers, so you would need an ARM kernel driver which are uncommon at this point. Emulating an Intel Windows install would be the only (slower) option.

Comment: Installing drivers in a VM to communicate with connected hardware while the host OS does not understand the device... That's always a gamble. I don't know what the success-rate on Macs is, but with other OS combo's I've given up on that approach.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - it depends on how you're virtualising & what the VM software can do compared to what the OS can do. Parallels doesn't emulate, so it's ARM only. UTM does emulate, all kinds of things, ARM, PPC [but not GPU]… Try it & see.

Comment: UTM just happens to be able to do both virtualization (VM) or emulation (which isn't a VM unless you use the term loosly). It won't help you emulate an x86 driver inside an ARM VM though, so it's likely you will need to emulate the whole machine.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - UTM doesn't need the installed guest OS to be ARM-specific. We're still down to … just try it & see. It's not something any of us are going to be able to test as we don't have the first clue what the hardware is or what driver it may need. The OP will have to do it.

Answer (score 22):

## Not directly.

The reasons why are complicated and probably not at all interesting to you given that you’re asking this question at all.

### But depending on the device, a virtual machine running Windows may work.

It is increasingly common that ‘specialized’ peripherals just connect over either plain USB (that is, not a USB-C alt mode and not Thunderbolt) or a routable network connection (usually an IP link over either Ethernet or WiFi). Aside from being easier to work with and less dependent on specific hardware, devices like that have a rather distinct advantage in that they are often trivial to use from a virtual machine.

If the device in question connects in such a way, then it’s extremely likely that you can just set up a virtual machine on your Mac running Windows (as opposed to having it installed ‘natively’), configure appropriate device pass-through behavior, and then use the drivers in the VM.

Answer (score 7):

**Your mileage may vary.**

While the first thing that comes to mind in regard to device drivers is a small, device-specific and platform-specific piece of software that abstracts the device peculiarities to the operating system, this is not always the case.

- E.g. a lot of printer drivers are in fact a single file stating the printing language used (PostScript + version, PCL + version) and the printer capabilities (single/double sided, resolution, black/color, etc). For the postscript-type printers, these PPD files are pretty much universal between Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc. Installing a bare PPD in Windows is not really trivial so the driver usually comes with a program that installs it (and also installs a bunch of useless bloatware as well), but with some knowledge the file could be extracted from the package and used across the operating systems.
- Another hardware manufacturer strategy is to (silently) use a well-established communication protocol and to publish a "driver" that internally refers to an operating system's built-in driver. If this is the case, a careful dissection of the driver package may get the device up and running in another OS. E.g. most of the cell modems are exactly like this.
- A third possibility is that the manufacturer did not care to create a driver for the platform you like better, but someone else did. A lot of Linux/*BSD/MacOS drivers exist just because someone reverse-engineered the driver for Windows and wrote the one they need. Once a Linux driver exists, porting it to MacOS or BSD (or the other way round) is a lot less work so the probability gets even higher. A great deal of scanners and wi-fi boards are like this.
- The device may in fact not require "driver" and only a (scriptable) mechanism of getting the data in and out. Measurement logging devices are an example.
- Some (not  many, in fact) device drivers may be used with Wine emulator.

Of course, if everything else fails, one could try using a Windows virtual machine like explained in the other answers.

If you reveal the type, make and model of the device in question, you may get a better advice.

Answer (score 3):

No. It is a long time since I wrote any devices drivers (3rd quarter of the previous century), but the code was *very* machine specific. I wrote for the idiosyncrasies of my hardware, and didn't worry about anything else. Two thoughts come to mind, however:

1. Does your device talk anything vaguely standard, such as USB, so you could interface crudely, and maybe worry about the idiosyncrasies yourself?
2. Have you investigated whether there is perhaps a Python or R library for controlling the device? Maybe on Github? I find it is rare for me to be the first person on the planet who has tried to get whatever-it-is to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is at least 1 NDISWrapper port for MacOS, so the answer is a strong maybe, providing it is a network driver. We are talking of years gone by when we speak of this so what applies today may not work.

Your best bet is to go back to the Vendor of this specialised device and ask them. They may have a "not ready" driver thay can give you under the table.

Comment: It would appear this only worked for WDM drivers, not WDF, so went out of fashion about 2006, along with WinXP. Last Mac port was 2005.